# Xamarin is end-of-life; what is its replacement for developing an Android app in C# Net?

Tags: c#, android, .net, cross-platform, maui

Im a .NET Developer, I want to develop a android app with c# ,

i need long term supported language framework to work on,

because Xamarin will end soon ,

Please advice

I tried to create a project in visual studio , i found a android app
but its not Xamarin and not MAUI

Comment: Have you tried following the getting started guide?
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/maui/first-app-tutorial/intro

Comment: Xamarin has been replaced with MAUI, so MAUI is your best choice for mobile development in C#, for the next few years.

Comment: Both the above comments miss the mark. This is not surprising, since Microsoft has done a terrible, horrible, very bad job of explaining **single-platform** vs **cross-platform** development in **.Net 6+**. Google can't even find the correct answer; all it returns is Microsoft links about Maui. The correct answer is `.Net Android`, which is the project template `Android Application: A project for creating a .Net Android Application`. This is the rebranding of `Xamarin.Android`. It uses Android APIs. `Maui` is `cross-platform UI`. Not the same at all.

Comment: I've voted to re-open the question, because it isn't necessarily seeking a recommendation. It could be worded better, but its essence is: **"Xamarin is end-of-life; what is its replacement for developing an Android app in C#"**? I've given Microsoft's answer in my preceding comment. Note that OP did find the correct project template; they just didn't know it, because Microsoft has utterly failed at communicating that "Xamarin (platform name)" has become simply ".Net (platform name)".

Comment: @Neil thanks for helping i will tried it today

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve good opinion , with you bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think they are mostly 2 options that are offered to you. Either on MAUI as you mentioned. It is the successor of Xamarin therefore will have a long term support.

Or you can opt for Unity https://unity.com/solutions/mobile/android-game-development if your application is more of a game

Comment: You should always add suggestions as comments!

Comment: thanks for helping , but unity mostly for gamming , also you can develop an app but its too hard and there is no resources

Answer (score 5):

I concur with the comments regarding the lack of clear communication from Microsoft in transitioning from Xamarin to .NET MAUI. Given the multiple components involved, I'll provide the following breakdown:

1. **Xamarin.Forms** -> **.NET MAUI**: This is the principal change of the rebranding. Xamarin.Forms (https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms) has been succeeded by .NET MAUI (https://github.com/dotnet/maui). Xamarin.Forms will reach end-of-life on May 1, 2024.
2. **Xamarin.Android** -> **.NET for Android**: In essence, Xamarin.Android is .NET for Android, since all .NET for Android releases still come from the same source code repository (https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android). For the latest release, there are some configuration changes which you can refer to Microsoft document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/android-projects?view=net-maui-8.0. However, these are just project configuration changes. We should not think .NET for Android is something totally new.
3. **Xamarin.iOS** -> **.NET for iOS**: .NET for iOS is essentially the same as Xamarin.iOS, and both versions are released from https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios.
4. **Xamarin.Mac** -> **.NET for Mac**: .NET for Mac (https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios) is merely a different configuration build of the same repository as xamarin.macios, which they execute using Mac Catalyst.